# Состояние гонки данных

Tags: c++, многопоточность, инкремент

Есть ли что-то "опасное" в том, что два потока будут одновременно инкрементировать одну переменную? Я имею ввиду, может ли произойти такое, что однажды переменная увеличится не на 1, а на любое другое число или вообще не увеличится? Для примера есть такое код:

```
unsigned long long g_count = 0;

std::thread t1([&]()
{
    while (true)
        ++g_count;
});

std::thread t2([&]()
{
    while (true)
        ++g_count;
});
```

Comment: В реально многопоточной (на аппаратном уровне) системе такое поведение вы наверняка увидите

Comment: Не «может», а обязательно произойдёт. GCC компилирует инкремент как последовательность из чтения в регистр, его инкремент и запись обратно. Так как у вас нет никаких барьеров, то потоки будут взаимно вклиниваться между этими тремя операциями, из-за чего у вас будет очень частое отсутствие инкремента на очередной итерации цикла.

Comment: Здесь до "гонки данных" дело и не дойдет. В С++ бесконечные циклы, которые не выполняют ввода/вывода, не доступаются к `volatile` переменным, не используют синхронизации и не выполняют атомарных операций - это неопределенное поведение. Многие компиляторы просто выкинут эти циклы из кода, как "ничего не делающие" (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1528.htm). Сделайте свою переменную `volatile` - тогда вопрос будет иметь смысл.